# Xcode UIViewController to customUIViewController without IB

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a UIViewController, and inside that view controller I would like to call a CustomUIViewController without the use of Interface Builder. I've been using this and it works but it requires a storyboard ID.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
UIViewController *myVC = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageID"];
[self presentModalViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

Is there a way of going from a UIViewController to a customViewController without the use of segues and IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
UIViewController *myVc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:myVc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will obviously present a new blank view controller, if you want your PageID view then you replace `UIViewController` with the name of the `PageID` class (i,e the .h/.m file names)

So i'm assuming this:

```
PageID *myVc = [[PageID alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:myVc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you want it inside a navigation controller do:

```
PageID *myVc = [[PageID alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVc];
[self presentViewController: navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

OR if you don't want it to be modal (don't need to create a new navigation controller as it will be added to the existing navigation controller stack i.e. `[self navigationController]`:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myVc animated:YES];
```

Comment: No problems. Mark as answer so other people know if they want the same solution :-)